# Is it ok to use elliptical trainer barefoot?

Tags: training

It turns out that, while I'm working out at a elliptical trainer, it much comfortable to me to be barefoot than to wear any kind of footwear. So this is something completely different from treadmill - I mean, you definitely need sneakers not to feel uncomfortable.

My question is - is it ethical to use public elliptical trainer barefoot, in socks only.

I know it sounds pretty strange, but I regret hadn't I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most commercial gyms require you to wear shoes of some sort while on the exercise floor.  A big part of it is health regulations, as well as insurance related.  Don't be surprised if one of the people who works at the gym asks you to put shoes on.

If you own the equipment, you can do what you want.  However, do check the rules of your gym.  Also consider that you would be placing yourself at a greater risk of athlete's foot.

Comment: I'd add that, other than the risk of picking up fungus, elliptical trainers are relatively safe to use barefoot. Unlike treadmills, there are very few "pinch spots" where your foot can get caught.

Comment: Agreed.  I can usually use an elliptical if my leg or feet are injured.